# How to get checked row values in WPF Gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I have created gridview in WPF with two columns. One for DataGridTextColumn and another one is DataGridCheckBoxColumn.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1">

 <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyString" Binding="{Binding MyString}" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="MyBool" Binding="{Binding MyBool}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Now, I want to get the checked items text value,

```
var SelectedList = new List<checkedBoxIte>();
            StringBuilder aa = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = dataGrid1.Items[i];
                var mycheckbox = dataGrid1.Columns[1].GetCellContent(item) as CheckBox;
                var myTextBox = dataGrid1.Columns[0].GetCellContent(item) as TextBox;
                if ((bool)mycheckbox.IsChecked)
                {
                    SelectedList.Add(item[i]);
                    //aa.Append(myTextBox.Text);
                }
            }
```

How, can i do this.

Comment: What doesn't work? What is `checkedBoxIte`?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a `TextBox`, you should use a [`TextBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, because that's what your `DataGridView` actually contains in `WPF`.

So change your code like this:

```
var SelectedList = new List<checkedBoxIte>();
StringBuilder aa = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var item = dataGrid1.Items[i];
    var mycheckbox = dataGrid1.Columns[1].GetCellContent(item) as CheckBox;
    var myTextBlock = dataGrid1.Columns[0].GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock;
    if ((bool)mycheckbox.IsChecked)
    {
        SelectedList.Add(item[i]);
        aa.Append(myTextBlock.Text);
    }
}
```